# webview_flutter does not show video thumbnail

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

When I use the webview_flutter and load a page with an HTML5 Video, there is no autogenerated thumbnail, similar to "real" browsers. On Android I get an ugly grey background instead and on iOS no thumbnail at all.

Is there any possibility to fix this? I would expect some kind of autogenerated thumbnail.

I have added a small code example and two screenshots.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = WebViewController();
    _controller.setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
    _controller.loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebViewWidget(controller: _controller);
  }
}
```

On Android it looks like this:

[image: Android webview]

On iOS it looks like this:

[image: iOS webview]

Answer (score 0):

Please add it:

```
WebView( initialMediaPlaybackPolicy: AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow, allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true）
```

Comment: for which WebView you are referring?